# Why was this morale building role question closed as "not constructive"?

Tags: discussion, closing

I am referring to this [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/who-is-supposed-to-be-responsible-for-team-building-morale-building-etc) here. This is a very simple question:

> is there a position that does this ( e.g,  morale building  etc)? Is
>   this a human resources job? And what is the scope and qualification
>   for human resources?

Either there is a position that specialize in motivating the team, or there isn't. As simple as that. I think this is a perfectly clear and valid question, but I don't know why the mod thought otherwise.

Another question is also clear cut and straightforward:

> And what is the scope and qualification for human resources?

From the context it should be very clear that I am not asking about the general work scope about human resource, but rather, the specific HR work scope that is related to the team. It is a well-defined question.

By simply closing well-meaning, clearly defined questions as "not constructive", I think the mods of this SE site is doing everything to harm the site. Oh, did I mention that we can't even [agree](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148/are-it-depends-answers-a-sign-of-a-bad-question) on [what](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219/is-not-constructive-really-applicable-at-workplace-se) [constitutes](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253/is-this-a-constructive-question-by-strict-definition) a "not constructive" question?

Comment: I didn't close it, but from your question I'm unclear what an "admin officer" is and why "morale building" or "bonus setting" would be tasks for the HR department

Comment: [NickC's answer](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/286/26) pretty thoroughly explains why I closed it *so that more clarification could be provided*. Note that closures *are not permanent*; the assumption (or at least hope) is that people will improve their questions.

Answer (score 6):

You have at least two questions in one.

> And what is the scope and qualification for human resources?

That is a separate question (and probably too broad on its own, as well.)

Also, I think you are over-complicating things with the first comment about your previous question and the admin officer.  Essentially you are saying:

1. I have learned that morale-building ***and other HR tasks*** are not a standard job responsibility for admin officers. (Here you assume that morale-building ***is*** an HR responsibility)
2. Is there a role for which morale-building (etc.) is a standard job function? (This is a good question, in my opinion, except you should define the "etc" explicitly.)
3. Is this an HR job? (Here you ask the question that you already assumed the answer to earlier.)

So, remove the second question, and link to the previous question if you want but don't assume any "takeaways" from it except that you are looking for a position that does provide these job responsibilities.  Clearly define what you are looking for and I would reopen the question if the other moderators who've already looked at this question (or the community) agree.  If the others don't agree, I can't place a vote, because it would be binding.

Comment: I've made the changes, reduce the two questions to one.

Comment: Yes, I think both mods and the community would vote to reopen any question that defines clearly what is being asked -- if what is being asked is not overly broad. That's the whole point of the process! :)

Answer (score 6):

See, it wasn't *that* hard, the question is now open.

---

The [current version](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/1567/5) of the question is:

> From my previous question it is clear that a simple admin officer ( not business admin) is not expected by default, to take on the crucial human-resource roles, such as morale building, employee welfare, bonus setting, and other jobs that require specific skills and that are crucial for my company's growth and survival.
>
> So, the question is, is there a position that does this?

It's still feels not constructive to me:

> From my previous question it is clear that a simple admin officer ( not business admin) is not expected by default..

Your opinions on your previous question are irrelevant to *this* question.

> ...to take on the crucial human-resource roles, such as morale building, employee welfare, bonus setting,

What makes you think morale building, employee welfare, bonus setting, are HR tasks. Are you asking or telling?

> ...and other jobs that require specific skills and that are crucial for my company's growth and survival.

This could potentially include *everything*, it can't get any vaguer than that.

---

I would gladly cast my re-open vote *if*:

- You remove the irrelevant stuff about your previous question,
- Pick a couple of *specific and related* tasks to ask about, and *nothing more*,
- Tell us what's your role in the company,
- Stop reverting good edits and start using full words. What was the point of reverting "administration" to "admin"?

Comment: The admin thing is even more confusing because of the last question really. When I hear admin I don NOT think administrative assistant, I assume it's either a systems administrator or a management position.

Comment: I completely agree with your bullet points about when you would cast a reopen vote.

Comment: I've done the edit.

Comment: @Graviton And I've just voted to re-open.